# Improving database performance (or) avoiding performance issues of database table with auto-generated primary key

Tags: java, sql, performance, jdbc

Our application has a table which stores all transactions records of clients in one single database table which has a auto-generated key as primary key. We have started to receive around 25K records each day now and am started to wonder if this at some point of time will cause a performance issue.

Background:
Transactions table contain all the details of each transaction our client (in real world, they are food vendors{say Kellogs cereals} and distributors{say Walmart}) perform every day. Initially, the design did not specify any logical/functional field that could serve as a primary key for a transaction and hence the DB developer went ahead and added a auto-generated key to "fill-in" the primary key. Since the client need to have all information on the front-end, the query is always `SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS`. The table has close to 80 columns and now has grown to 100K records.

Database: Oracle 11g
Core business logic implemented in: Java 1.5 (JDBC driver for querying)
Front-end : SmartGWT

Query:
Assuming fetching all the records all the time will start hammering the performance at some point, I wanted to seek any database design / query tweaks / general suggestions that I should consider to avoid performance issue or improve performance of the module.

Comment: The only sensible thing to do if you are only going to query it by time is to partition by range on the date; also, you should obviously only query X rows at once (some sort of pagination is generally used on the frontend for this). Having an autogenerated PK doesn't have any performance impact here.

Comment: agree with @viruzzo, you shouldn't wonder about 100K rows, think eBay!

Comment: Also, do you really need 80 columns? It's impossible to tell without knowing your model, but I doubt that all of them will be meaningful for most of the rows, and that you would need to query them all every time.

Comment: Let's assume each row takes only 10 bytes. You have 80 columns and 100K rows. That makes 80 MBs of data that would have to go from the database to the client's browser. Not only will it be real slow, but you will make the browser's memory explode, to display a whole bunch of data that is not usable. Who can handle 100000 rows of data without querying it? Start designing a real GUI, with searching, filtering and sorting enabled, using the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 11 lets you create interval partitions. I think transaction date is a good candidate for partition key. I don't see any reason to show all the transactions to end users ( at least every time). Usually it's enough to display just last week/month data... Retrieving complete list of transactions can be handled differently (storing consolidate balance, using readonly tables that keep historical data, etc).
Also, having 80 columns in a single table looks quite suspicious to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so already, I suggest adding an index on the vendor ID and changing the query to be like:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE VENDOR_ID = :Vendor
```